# How to Save WebView State in Fragment?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a tiny web browser using Android's WebView and Jetpack Navigation Component.

The problem appears when I load a URL on the Home Page and then navigate to the Settings page and then come back to the Home Page, the WebView reloads itself. Even though I am saving its state to a `Bundle` in ViewModel, that somehow remembers the page on which the webview was last time and reloads that URL. But that's not what I want. I want to save the **STATE** means everything related to WebView like the scroll position, if there is any video then the position of seekbar on that video, etc everything. Please let me know if there is anything more than I can help you with.

Here is how I implemented that

ViewModel:

```
class WebViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var webViewState: Bundle = Bundle()
    
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    private lateinit var webView: CustomWebView
    private val viewModel: WebViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onPause() {
      super.onPause()
      Log.i(TAG, "onPause: ")
      webView.saveState(viewModel.webViewState)
   }

   override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
      binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(
          inflater,
          container,
          false
      )
      return binding.root
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      initViews()
   }

   private fun initViews() {
      webView = CustomWebView(requireContext())
      binding.apply {
        frameLayout.addView(webView)
        layoutBottomBar.rLTextBarContainer.setOnClickListener {
            showSearchFragment()
        }
        layoutBottomBar.ivBottomMenu.setOnClickListener {
            showBottomMenu()
        }
        layoutBottomBar.ivRefreshOrCancel.setOnClickListener {
            refreshOrCancelClicked()
        }
    }

    if (viewModel.webViewState.isEmpty) {
        Log.i(TAG, "initViews: WebViewModel webViewState is empty")
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com")
    } else
        webView.restoreState(viewModel.webViewState)

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code and when came back to first fragment, state was restored correctly. and by state I mean the scrolling position.

Comment: So the page was not reloaded at all?

Comment: I don't know if it reloaded  or not, but the state was saved.

Comment: Ok I tried this scenario. I loaded first page and then I went to second page and turned off wifi. When i came back state was saved.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it works to some extent but if you visit Youtube, play any video, and then navigate to the settings page and come back, it will reload the page and starts the video from the beginning. Or if you turn off the internet, the WebView error page will be shown.

Comment: Yes. I think it is related to how the actual web page is implemented.

Comment: Possibly, but that makes this solution invalid.

Comment: I guess. You can work around this. For example saving the webview object into view model. But you should be aware of memory leaks and handle them.

Comment: Yeah, that' 's the problem. I am not that level of developer. Can you recommend any good sources to learn about that?

Comment: For start you can add "leak canary" library to your debug builds. It automatically warns you about memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this. And that is to save webview object into your viewmodel. But you should be aware of possible memory leaks and other problems and handle them.
For handling memory leaks, one step is to manually detach webview from its parent, in onViewDestroy lifecycle callback and attach it in onViewCreated lifecycle callback.